# how to change a comment structure in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, comments

i am working on my wordpress theme, and comment time/date are showing up in one continuous timestamp tag:

```
<time datetime="2015-12-21T19:09:49+00:00"> december 21st,  2015 on 19:09 </time>
```

i would like to have the time of day be wrapped in a span tag, so i can style it with css. the comment.php file on my theme uses this to list the comments, and there's no way to edit the timestamp here:

```
    <ol class="comment-list">
        <?php
            wp_list_comments( array(
                'style'       => 'ol',
                'format'      => 'html5',
                'short_ping'  => true,
            ) );
        ?>
    </ol>
```

i tried looking at my theme's functions.php, as well as wordpress' include files: comment.php and comment-template.php. none of them deal with the actual tag structure of the time-stamp, so there was nothing there for me to play with.

does anyone have any idea how i can do this? obviously, i'd rather do it in my theme's functions.php than alter the wp inc stuff..

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Usually the comment date stamp is defined by :
.comment-metadata a, .pingback .comment-edit-link
Search for something like this in style.css and you can style them.

Comment: the CSS part is not my problem. i want to style the hour differently than the date... i need to get it into a span to be able to to that in the CSS. i tried searching in all of wordpress' php files for any of the aforementioned tags, including the time tag (which is pretty unique), and didn't find anything :(

Comment: you can style the date and time of the comment from .comment-metadata a in style.css you can also remove it from the grouped selector that I've written in the answer and style it individually because if you change the grouped selector it will apply it on the edit link and pingbacks either.

Comment: .comment-metadata a is the default style that comments date and time use in wordpress it's called in the core I think that's why you can't see it in the template files.